# Adobe Caslon Pro, pdflatex, sync-tex busy

Tags: fonts, errors

I installed (as far as I am concerned, they are installed [per this guide](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/fonts/psfonts/adobe/adobecaslon/adobecaslon.pdf)) Adobe Caslon Pro and when I try to build the following `test.tex` file TexMaker gives no error, but produces no .pdf file either. I also observe the following file: `test.synctex(busy)`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[rmdefault]{adobecaslon}

\PassOptionsToPackage{  
  protrusion  =true,
  expansion   =true,
  tracking    =true,
  letterspace =50,
  final}{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

What am I supposed to look for?

Comment: Do you have the commercial fonts installed somewhere?

Comment: Compile on a command line to see what's happening. Or check the log-file.

Comment: @Ulrike I get `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file awrg____.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font file for r eading` Does that mean that there is a problem with the .pfb files?

Comment: It means that you either don't have the pfb or that there are in the wrong place or that your file name data base is not up-to-date.